# How do I display a "loading.." while <iframe ..> </iframe> is not ready?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I display a "loading.." while `<iframe id="pdfViewer" name="pdfViewer" src="foo.pdf"></iframe>` are not ready? I'm not web developer. My first try was do it by using JavaScript, but:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.Open("GET", "foo.pdf");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if(this.readyState == 4) { 
      document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = this.responseText;
   }
}
xhr.send(null);
```

I can't use jQuery solutions here because I can't use it.

Comment: Use jQuery and attach a `.load()` event. This question has been asked like 30 times already, so use one of the existing solutions.

Comment: use css wrapper and display loading while contain loading, once loaded replace wrapper content with loaded value

Comment: @Blender: I can't use Jquery..

Comment: @JapanPro: Can you give me a link or an code example simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial example: [jsfiddle.net/G5wkS/](http://jsfiddle.net/G5wkS/)

```
var placeholder = document.createElement('div');
placeholder.textContent = 'Loading...';
document.body.appendChild(placeholder);
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.setProperty('display', 'none');
placeholder.parentNode.insertBefore(iframe, placeholder.nextSibling);
iframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
    placeholder.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);
    iframe.style.removeProperty('display');
});
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'http://127.0.0.1/');
```

Create a placeholder and an iframe (initially hidden).  Of course you could choose to write these out in HTML too, and place them wherever you want with your own styling and attributes.  Then, once the iframe's `onload` fires, take away the placeholder and unhide the iframe.  You might want to do something different if the `onerror` event fires instead.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. Is there some way to instead of `src` accpet a binary string?

Comment: @Jack: A [`data:` URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) may be the way to go.  Writing binary data into an existing page, which has already been detected as MIME type `text/html`, is unlikely to yield satisfactory results.

Comment: :But is there no someway to set(or re-set) the content type of current page by using javascript? I have tried this: `var metatag = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0];

    metatag.setAttribute("http-equiv", "Content-type");
    metatag.setAttribute("content", "application/pdf");
    document.body.innerHTML = binaryString;
` and +1, of course.

Comment: I tried using your code, I changed `http://127.0.0.1/` to `foo.pdf' and too `http://127.0.0.1/foo.pdf´ but it display `Loading...` forever.. I tried with small files too.

Comment: @Jack: Nope, `<meta>` is far too late to be able to change content-type (the browser has already parsed HTML to the DOM).  The above code works perfectly for me in jsFiddle on Chrome; it should work in Firefox as well, but most versions of IE lack the modern `addEventListener`.  What are you using?

Comment: `iframe.setAttribute('src', 'http://127.0.0.1/');` works fine. But `iframe.setAttribute('src', 'foo.pdf');` returns the above error. I'm using Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0):

another approach
see , you can create overlay kind of div and programatically place it above the iframe.Once the contents is ready hide the overlay.